react native doesn't get old documents from firestore
Expo react native app doesn't get old documents inserted in another execution of the app from firestore.
I'm executing my expo react native on my cellphone using:
npx expo run:android
If I add one or more documents, I can get from the firestore the documents inserted using the commands below.
If I stop the execution and restart my app using the command above, then I can't get from firestore the documents created before, but if I create another document in that execution of the app, that document I can get.
I thought that react native was getting the documents from the app cache, then I entered in Settings --> Apps --> MyApp --> Clean Cache on my Android, but it didn't solve the problem.
This behaviour is because of the settings persistence:false, but how can I force to get all documents? Is there a command for it?
I printed the pending writes, and all fetched documents are on the server, isn't it to get all documents?
my code:
  async function bootstrap() {
    await firestore().settings({
      // persistence: false, // disable offline persistence
    });
    db = firestore();
  }

  function getDocument(){
    const usersCollection = db.collection('Users');
    usersCollection.get().then((documentSnapshot) => {
      documentSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
      });
      ...
  }

  function createDocument(){
      ...
      usersCollection.add(user).then(() => {
        Alert.alert('Document added!');
      })
      ...
  }

  async function getMarker() {
    const snapshot = await db.collection('Users').get()
    let markers = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.id);
    markers.forEach(m => getPending(m));
  }

  function getPending(id:string){
    db.collection("Users").doc(id).onSnapshot((d:any) => {
      var source = d.metadata.hasPendingWrites ? "Local" : "Server";
      console.log("from server:", source, " from cache: ", d.metadata.fromCache, " data: ", d.data());
    });
  }

The documents come from the server and from the cache.
I changed the default get behavior, but didn't solve the problem.
usersCollection.get({source:'server'}).then((documentSnapshot) => {

firestore console:

console log:


REPOSITORY
The app github repository:
https://github.com/danilobatistaqueiroz/react-native-firebase
You can download, add the missing below files, compile and run using your firebase.
I removed from repository these files:
/firebaseConfig.js
/.firebaserc
/android/app/google-services.json

It was an instability in my computer, maybe after a system update.
